# p:remotecommand to upload files

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to upload file programatically to my jsf application. The user should select a directory on his system, and a js script should loop on any file in dir and send each one to the listener serverside
I cannot use FileUpload, because it cannot select a whole dir with thousands of file, so I was thinking to use jquery and send the file to a remotecommand, but I have no clue to how send the file itself (normally I pass just string)

Answer (score 0):

> so I was thinking to use jquery and send the file to a remotecommand, but I have no clue to how send the file itself

Don't go there. It is a bad attempt to a workaround for a bad design choice. You'd most likely run into similar problems and what about the user selecting a lot of files for second time if it fails halfway? It might become slow, might run into browser limits (search for uploading multiple files in plain html)...

If you still want to do it via a webbrowser (which according to one of your other questions you do not want to), maybe try something like https://webdeltasync.github.io/ (disclaimer: I did not use it myself, and there might be similar ones (https://www.google.com/search?q=browser+based+rsync), it is just a hint in which direction to find a real solution)